# laser_frame not moving

Tags: gazebo, rviz, urdf, base-link, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following scheme in simulation enviroment with Gazebo and Rviz:
laser_frame -> base_link -> base_stabilized -> base_footprint -> odom -> map -> world

laser_frame to base_link is provided by robot_state_publisher looking up in the urdf file

base_link -> base_stabilized -> base_footprint -> odom is provided by a 'message_to_tf' node that takes ground_truth topic with z axis and rotation to publish this transformations

odom -> map is provided by a mapper node setting up the transforms in x-axis and y-axis

map -> world is provided by a node doing a static/fixed transform

In Rviz we have as fixed frame and target frame the /world frame.
World is fixed, map is fixed refering to world, odom is moving in x,y,z and rotation refering to map BUT base_footprint, base_link and therefore laser_frame arent moving. They keep as they started.

How can I fix it? What am I missing?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190950/laser_frame-not-moving/) by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-22**:
Are the "->" arrows here displaying parent->child arrows? If yes, are there maybe more frames? Then you'd have multiple parents and TF will do unpredictable stuff.

**Comment by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on 2014-08-22**:
Yes, they are parent->child. There are any more frames, its the complete chain

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-22**:
Usually they are all the other way around. If it is exactly one chain it should work though. You can add a TF display and see if everything is connected.

**Comment by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on 2014-08-22**:
Thanks for the reply @dornhege The tf chain was perfect. The problem is explained below. Feel free to ask if I havent explained well.

**Comment by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on 2014-08-26**:
Can you @dornhege mark my answer as correct? I dont have karma > 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was in the odometry sent to 'message_to_tf' node.
Message_to_tf is meant to provide intermediate transforms between /base_link and /odom.
Odom is my odometry without z value so it was moving, but base_link wasnt. Why?
I was passing to 'message_to_tf' and odometry message identical to ground_truth published by Gazebo but with x,y position and rotation set to 0.
The problem is that z rotation wasnt 0 so odom moved in yaw but base_link kept static.

So the answer is: In the following scenario (quadrotor flying), being /odom the odometry without z-value, the odometry message that we must pass to 'message_to_tf' to obtain intermediate transforms between /odom and /base_link (defined in the urdf file) must have only the z component of position and all the remain values to 0 (keeping quaternion normalized)

---

Originally posted by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) with karma: 93 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0